# ftp and smb connection

Tags: ios, ftp, smb

In my application want to to ftp and smb connection.
[FTP](https://github.com/albertodebortoli/GoldRaccoon)

for FTP I got this and for smb [this](https://github.com/38leinaD/tango) I have used. But I want to use only 1 SDK for both. Is there any SDK is available so I can use for both ftp and smb  ?

Any help would be appreciated.